# Can I automate assignment of the 'CmsExperiences' All Sites standard tab?

Tags: community, tab, digital-experience

Can I automate assignment of the 'CmsExperiences' All Sites standard tab?

I tried to execute a command

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Profile:Admin,CustomTab:CmsExperiences` to retrieve Admin profile access to `My Sites` tab but I received an error.

`Entity of type 'CustomTab' named 'CmsExperiences' cannot be found`

I need to migrate access to this tab from one sandbox to another so that I could deactivate the old Digital Experience Site

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a standard tab, the actual command to retrieve these settings should be

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Profile:Admin,CustomTab:standard-CmsExperiences
```

Still, there is warning that we can't actually retrieve the definition of this tab

```
=== Retrieved Source Warnings

 FILE NAME              PROBLEM                        
 ────────────────────── ────────────────────────────── 
 unpackaged/package.xml Cannot retrieve a standard tab
```

but we don't want to retrieve the definition of this tab, just Admin access to it.

Now in the `admin.profile-meta.xml file` four additional lines appeared

```
<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>standard-CmsExperiences</tab>
    <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
```

which we now can use to set this tab available on another sandbox.

And now we can deploy this tab visibility to another org using command

`sfdx force:source:deploy -m Profile:Admin -u target-org`